# Who is the msg.sender in the context when calling the "super.{....}" contract method on the inherited parent contract?

Tags: solidity, inheritance, msg.sender

The child contract's method is: (1)

```
function redeem(
        uint256 shares,
        address receiver,
        address owner
    ) public override andSync returns (uint256 assets) {
        return super.redeem(shares, receiver, owner);
    }
```

The parent contract's method is: (2)

```
function redeem(
        uint256 shares,
        address receiver,
        address owner
    ) public virtual returns (uint256 assets) {
        if (msg.sender != owner) {
            uint256 allowed = allowance[owner][msg.sender]; // Saves gas for limited approvals.

            if (allowed != type(uint256).max) allowance[owner][msg.sender] = allowed - shares;
        }

        // Check for rounding error since we round down in previewRedeem.
        require((assets = previewRedeem(shares)) != 0, "ZERO_ASSETS");

        beforeWithdraw(assets, shares);

        _burn(owner, shares);

        emit Withdraw(msg.sender, receiver, owner, assets, shares);

        asset.safeTransfer(receiver, assets);
    }
```

Who is the `msg.sender` in (2) when called from (1)?

The child contract inherits the parent contract:

```
contract MPERC4626 is xERC4626 { ... }
```